# how to return a view with array variable from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In the controller I have this variable

```
$_colors = ['dummy1','dummy2','dummy3'];
```

I return the view using this code

```
return view('view')->with(['colors'=>$_colors]);
```

in the page.blade.php , I try to catch the variable inside a  tag

```
<script>
     var colors = "{{$colors}}";
</script>
```

unfortunately , it fires error :

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use

```
<script>
     var colors = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($colors, true) !!}');
</script>
```

which will encode your PHP array into a JSON string and then decode this string within the JavaScript code.

You can also try.

```
<script>
     var colors = JSON.parse('{!! $colors !!}');
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need `JSON.parse()` as well. So maybe try `var colors = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($colors, true) !!}');`

Comment: Thanks - worked , I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$_colors`, which you assigned to `$colors` is an array. As you are putting it inside javascript code in the view, it'd be reasonable to print it as a json string with:

```
<script>
    var colors = {!! json_encode($colors) !!};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment the answer above, but in that example above you'll need the JSON.parse() because the json encoded string from php is put between quotation marks, what makes it a string instead of a json object. So I think it should work without the JSON.parse() when you miss out the quotation marks.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`, so `htmlspecialchars()` won't be used when printing the string from `json_encode()`. I edited the answer.